# Labels disappear from the CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im using a collectionView, in the first indexPath row i have a summary of data from the first viewController retrieved from Firebase, from the second onwards i have hid all label and showed others but when i go back to the first view and return into the collectionView labels disappear

It's a problem with constraints or is my bad code? You can look at right side 3 labels disappearing

Before:

[image: First]

After:

[image: Second]

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cella = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withReuseIdentifier: "cella", for: indexPath) as! ChatViewCell
        cella.LabelEur.text = ""
        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally)
            cella.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor("#FFA000").cgColor

            cella.Label1.textColor = .white
            cella.LabelR.textColor = .white
            cella.Date.textColor = .white
            cella.Time.textColor = .white
            cella.City.textColor = .white

            let user = Chat[indexPath.row]
            cella.Label1.text = user.sender
            cella.LabelEur.isHidden = true
            cella.euro.isHidden = true
            cella.Tipo.isHidden = false
            cella.Quantita.isHidden = false
            cella.Misure.isHidden = false
            cella.TIpo2.isHidden = false
            cella.Label1.isHidden = false
            cella.labeldata.isHidden = true
            cella.labelora.isHidden = true
            cella.Date.text = user.date
            cella.Time.text = user.time

            if user.caricoc == "1" {
                cella.CaricoC.isHidden = false
            } else { cella.CaricoC.isHidden = true }
            if user.runflat == "1" {
                cella.RunFlat.isHidden = false
            } else { cella.RunFlat.isHidden = true }
            if user.rinforzato == "1" {
                cella.Rinforzato.isHidden = false
            } else { cella.Rinforzato.isHidden = true }
            cella.montaggio.isHidden = true
            cella.oraMontaggio.isHidden = true
            cella.Distanza.isHidden = true
            cella.categoria.isHidden = false
            cella.categoria.text = user.cat
            cella.TIpo2.text = user.tipo
            cella.Misure.text = user.model
            cella.Tipo.text = user.marca
            cella.Quantita.text = user.numero
            cella.LabelR.text = "Ha inserito una richiesta"
            //key2 = user.key
            misure1 = user.model
            caricC = user.caricoc
            rnf = user.runflat
            rinf = user.rinforzato
            tipo = user.tipo
            marca = user.marca
            quantita = user.numero
            cat = user.cat
            //last = user.lastname
            lat = user.lat
            lng = user.lng
        }else{

        }
        if (indexPath.row >= 1){
            let user = Chat[indexPath.row]
            cella.Label1.text = ""
            cella.Date.text = user.date
            cella.Time.text = user.time
            cella.RunFlat.isHidden = true
            cella.Rinforzato.isHidden = true
            cella.CaricoC.isHidden = true
            cella.LabelEur.isHidden = false
            cella.categoria.isHidden = true
            cella.euro.isHidden = false
            cella.TIpo2.isHidden = true
            cella.Tipo.isHidden = true
            cella.Quantita.isHidden = true
            cella.labelora.isHidden = false
            cella.labeldata.isHidden = false
            cella.montaggio.isHidden = false
            cella.oraMontaggio.isHidden = false
            cella.Distanza.isHidden = false
            cella.oraMontaggio.text = user.oraApp
            cella.montaggio.text = user.dataApp
            cella.Misure.isHidden = true

            let prezzo: Float = (Float(user.text)?.multiplied(by: 1.10))!
            let nenno: Float = 3.234
            let prezzo2 = String(describing: NSDecimalNumber(string: String(format:"%.0f", prezzo)))
            cella.LabelEur.text = prezzo2
            cella.LabelR.isHidden = true
            cella.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor("#FFFFFF").cgColor
            let posInt = Int(user.positiondef)
            if (posInt! <= 5) {
                cella.Distanza.text = "A meno di 5km"
            } else if (posInt! <= 10) {
                cella.Distanza.text = "A meno di 10km"
            } else if (posInt! <= 15) {
                cella.Distanza.text = "A meno di 15 km"
            }
            /*
             if (user.positiondef != nil) {
             if (user.positiondef.hasPrefix("0")) {
             cella.Distanza.text = "Nelle vicinanze"
             } else {
             cella.Distanza.text = user.positiondef+"KM"
             }
             }*/
            cella.City?.text = user.city
            self.Chat = self.Chat.sorted{ $0.text.compare($1.text, options: .numeric) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }

        }

        return cella

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the constraints are correct. They shouldn’t be changing between viewController transitions. The problem may be with the label’s “textColor” attribute. In the first cell you are setting the color to white. In the second they should be black. I believe they aren’t displaying simply because they are the same color as the background. Try setting the textColor of the labels to black in the second “if” statement.

```
if indexPath.row >= 1 {
    //set textColor of labels here.
}
```

Collection Views use reusable cells, so the label’s textColor may still be white from being used previously.

Comment: Why if in the storyboard are sets black by default?

Comment: Because they are “Reusable Cells”. When you call “collectionView.dequeueReusableCell” You’re taking a previously created cell and setting new data on it. You’re not creating it from the storyboard. The cell will still have all of the old data on it. (Along with the label settings, such as text color)